# How to pass values to templates in tornado

Tags: python, templates, python-2.7, tornado

I have a template which displays a lot of values which are passed from a server, my question is how to i pass these values to the template file.
My Handler code is as follows:
    class AdminHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #respond to a get method
        #self.write("AdminHandler:: Inside GET function")

```
    userName = "Alwin Doss"
    welcomeMessage = "Good evening are you enjoying kids dance"
    items = {}
    items["userName"] = userName
    items["welcomeMessage"] = welcomeMessage


    self.render("web/admin.html", title="Admin Page", items=items)
```

and my template code is as follows:
    {% items['userName'] %}
    {% items['welcomeMessage'] %}
    {% end %}

Problem is that I am unable to access these values in the template file. I get the following error:

raise ParseError("unknown operator: %r" % operator)
ParseError: unknown operator: "items['userName']"
ERROR:root:500 GET /admin (127.0.0.1) 3.27ms

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a demonstration similar to what you seem to be doing. Look into the syntax of the template and see the different uses of `{%   %}` and the `{{   }}` blocks. This code:

```
from tornado import template

t = template.Template('''\
{% for user in users %} 
    {{ user['userName'] }} 
    {{ user['welcomeMessage'] }} 
{% end %}
''')

# create first user and append to a user list
users = []
user = { "userName" : "Alwin Doss",
        "welcomeMessage" : "Good evening are you enjoying kids dance"}
users.append(user)

# create and append second user
user = { "userName" : "John Smith",
        "welcomeMessage" : "Good evening, JS"}
users.append(user)

# render the template and output to console
print t.generate(users = users)
```

Produces this output:

```
Alwin Doss 
Good evening are you enjoying kids dance 

John Smith 
Good evening, JS
```

For more on Tornado templates have a look at [this tutorial](https://carlosgabaldon.wordpress.com/articles/tornado-templates/) and of course at the [Tornado templates documentation](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/latest/template.html).